# Как манипулировать массивами, определенными в классе?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, что не так...

```
// students.h
class NameStudents {
  public:
    void GetNameStudents() const;
  private:
    char *chNameStudents[3];
     chNameStudents[0] = "Bob";
     chNameStudents[1] = "Milan";
     chNameStudents[2] = "Edvard";
};

// student.cpp  
#include <iostream>
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;

void NameStudents::GetNameStudents() const const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << chNameStudents[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Stds Students;
    Stds.GetNameStudents();
}
```

ошибка:

> `In file included from /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:2:
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:7: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of 
>    member`chNameStudents'
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:7: error: making `chNameStudents' static
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:7: error: invalid in-class initialization 
>    of static data member of non-integral type`int[0]'
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:8: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of 
>    member `chNameStudents'
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:8: error: making`chNameStudents' static
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:8: error: invalid in-class initialization 
>    of static data member of non-integral type `int[1]'
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:9: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of 
>    member`chNameStudents'
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:9: error: making `chNameStudents' static
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:9: error: invalid in-class initialization 
>    of static data member of non-integral type`int[2]'
> In file included from /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:2:
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.h:10:3: warning: no newline at end of file
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp: In function `int main()':
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:13: error:`Stds' undeclared (first use 
>    this function)
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:13: error: (Each undeclared identifier is 
>    reported only once for each function it appears in.)
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:13: error: parse error before `;' token
> /GCC/3.3.3/samp/STUDENTS/students.cpp:18:2: warning: no newline at end of file`

Расскажите, как манипулировать массивами, определенными в классах?

Comment: Инициализируйте в конструкторе, при создании экземпляра класса.

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать char ** в плюсах как поле класса? Пользуйтесь средствами STL )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// students.h
class NameStudents {
  public:
    NameStudents()    
    {
      chNameStudents[0] = "Bob";
      chNameStudents[1] = "Milan";
      chNameStudents[2] = "Edvard";
    }
     void GetNameStudents() const;
  private:
    char *chNameStudents[3];
};

// student.cpp  
#include <iostream>
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;

void NameStudents::GetNameStudents() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << chNameStudents[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    NameStudents Students;
    Students.GetNameStudents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// student.cpp  
#include <iostream>  
#include "students.h"  
using namespace std;

void NameStudents::GetNameStudents() const  
{  
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)  
        cout << this->chNameStudents[i] << endl;  
}

int main()  
{  
      NameStudents Students;  
      Students.GetNameStudents();  
}
```

- ответ который выше

Comment: 1. Не this.varname, а this->varname, поскольку this - это указатель

2. В данном случае это излишне

Comment: 1 действительно
2 не думаю, что это настолько сложно, намного сложней разгребать потом проблемы, которые могут возникнуть
В этом примере это конечно смешно (я про проблемы), но приучаться к этому нужно с малых лет )))))